# Simple jQuery Gallery Selfmade?

Tags: jquery, gallery

I tried various Gallery plugins, but none fits my needs.

I have some markup as follows:

```
<div id='thumbs-list'>
    <div class='thumb-item'>
        <a href='big1.jpg'><img src='thumb1.jpg' /></a>
    </div>
    <div class='thumb-item'>
        <a href='big2.jpg'><img src='thumb2.jpg' /></a>
    </div>
    <div class='thumb-item'>
        <a href='big3.jpg'><img src='thumb3.jpg' /></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='fullsize'>
    <img src='big1.jpg' />
</div>
```

I want to swap the linked JPGs into the ID 'fullsize', preferably with some fading effect, but at least the image should switch.

How can I get started with a simple hence flexible jQ script? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".thumb-item a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $a = $(this);
    $("#fullsize img").fadeOut("slow", function(){
        $(this).attr("src", $a.attr("href")).fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

---

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/cp22v/

Comment: +1, but I would use: `$("a", "#thumbs-list")` since it's faster.

Comment: I don't know if that's the appropriate selector but it would work. I tried to make it specific based on the HTML. `$("#thumbs=list a")` would be faster than `$("a", "#thumbs-list")`

Comment: yeah, this already works licke a charm. However, my CSS makes it flicker a little bit because the image sizes vary. but I'll get to fix that somehow. Thanks!